# MYSQL: How to forbid a user to change his password?

Tags: mysql, passwords, privileges

A user can execute the command "SET PASSWORD" when logged in, and I was wondering if any1 knows if it is possible to disable the use of it. As searched, it seems that is it not.

thank you

Comment: seems like an odd request.  the user should be in charge of their own security.

Comment: Not really, since changing a user password is a direct access to the mysql database, it can be compromising for security concerns. FTP server does not allow changin a user password client-side. Why not Mysql.

Comment: any1 has a workaround or an idea on how i can forbid that command to be executed? thanks

Comment: It looks impossible. However I've thought of a workaround that could be to create a trigger on the mysql.user table to check when a new password is set and then do whatever (sync passwords between services, cancel the update or other).